# R - Invalid type (NULL) for variable message while creating a matrix

Tags: r, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to do one-hot encoding to a dataframe, so I'm following an online resource that I've found , but I'm receiving an error message such as below.

I have tried to Google it but everything points that there is something wrong with the dataset but I'm not able to find what.

```
> d_train  <- sparse.model.matrix(train$Tickets_Resolution ~ .-1, data=train)
   Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) : 
   invalid type (NULL) for variable 'train$Tickets_Resolution'
```

This is how it looks like `train` dataset.

```
str(tickets)
'data.frame':   71345 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Functional_Area  : Factor w/ 24 levels "0","812","APS",..: 12 7 7 3 7 23 23 12 23 7 ...
 $ Operating_Company: Factor w/ 28 levels " WS","812","BWI",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ Service_Type     : Factor w/ 20 levels "APS","CNC","DBA",..: 7 7 7 1 7 17 17 7 17 7 ...
 $ Ticket_Category  : Factor w/ 5 levels "BULK","CHG","HK",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Ticket_Resolution: Factor w/ 2 levels "Defect","OK": 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Priority         : Factor w/ 4 levels "Priority 1","Priority 2",..: 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 3 3 3 ...
 $ Quarter          : Factor w/ 3 levels "Quarter 1","Quarter 2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

head(train)
  Functional_Area Operating_Company Service_Type Ticket_Category Ticket_Resolution   Priority   Quarter
2             DCF               DCF          FUN              SR            Defect Priority 3 Quarter 1
3             DCF               DCF          FUN              SR                OK Priority 3 Quarter 1
4             APS               DCF          APS              SR            Defect Priority 3 Quarter 1
5             DCF               DCF          FUN              SR                OK Priority 3 Quarter 1
6             SEC               DCF          SEC              SR                OK Priority 4 Quarter 1
8             FUN               DCF          FUN              SR                OK Priority 3 Quarter 1
```

[Link to the dataset is included here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U2rWhV_uTbYdceEZAMUWH0dk43ve-bAg).

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are specifying a `data` to `sparse.model.matrix`, I don't think you should refer to it in the formula itself. See the documentation for `sparse.model.matrix`.

Comment: I notice all your characters are factors... when read in .csv, try: stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Comment: @AndrewBannerman I am re-factoring all the dataframe while processing it. May it has something to do?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I've checked the documentation and it seems to be fine as I wrote it.

Comment: try d_train  <- sparse.model.matrix(train$Ticket_Resolution ~ .-1, data=train), you have train$Tickets_Resolution versus Ticket_Resolution... just a typo!

Comment: @AndrewBannerman thank you very much! I didn't see it at all!